# how do i change zindex of child div with css3 delay

Tags: css, css-transitions, delay

css3 transition delay starts animation only after some time. its ok. but the animation is related to it only.

can we change the z-index of child div after 2s when mouse is hovered on it?

Things I have done:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="front"></div>
<div class="back"></div>
</div>

<style>
.parent:hover .front{
    transition-delay:4s;    
    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transition-delay:4s;
    z-index: -1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: the syntax should be .parent:hover

Comment: not working in IE 10...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version should work in all modern browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/aLEgJ/

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent .front {
    z-index: 1;
}

.parent .back {
    z-index: 0;
}

.parent:hover .front {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 4s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 4s;
    -o-transition-delay: 4s;
    transition-delay: 4s; 

    z-index: -1;
}
```